# Adding button to the lock screen in android

Tags: android, locking, screen

Is it possible to add a button to Android lock screen I want to perform some actions on it without unlocking the phone. Is it possible? Android System allows that?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, at least since Android 4.2 (or was it 4.3?) you can place widgets on the lock screen

Comment: Thank you for the response, can you tell me from where to start?

Comment: Google is always a good place to start :). Check out this page from the official API Guides, for example: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#lockscreen - I can't give you anything more specific, never developed a widget myself

Comment: https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2781801?hl=en